# Problems Suring Content Assist After Installing WindowBuilder plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder, content-assist

The following message pops up when I try to use the content assist command (Ctrl+Space) after I installed the WindowBuilder plug-in :

"The  'API Tools Javadoc Proposals' proposal from computer from the 'org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui' plug-in did not complete normally..."

I already tried to de-select the API Tools Javadoc Proposals on Content Assist, as the program sugests, but still did not work. I also tried to select all the Java Proposals, tried to change the Key and nothing worked. I need to use this plug-in for a important project. Does anybody know what can I do?

PS: I never had this problem with Eclipse before, I uninstalled and installed the  Window Builder plug-in to see what would happen, and the problem is definitely related to Window Builder.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571197

Comment: WB has its own combined editor (with three tabs) which looks broken. Right-clicking in the source tab and choosing "open with / Java Editor" will open a second editor.

Use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing an older version of Eclipse could work, and indeed it does.
I've installed Eclipse 2018-12 and the latest official (NOT prerelease) Window Builder version from the Eclipse Marketplace. Now the content assistant works fine.

IMPORTANT: You can have more than one Eclipse installation at the same time on your computer, as long as it is in a different folder. That's how I did it at least. Bad thing is, that you'll probably need another workspace separate from your everyday workspace, just for the Eclipse 2018-12 installation.

Comment: It was deleted because it contained spanish content. And hint: use paragraphs, and avoid anything that doesnt contribute to your answer, such as that complete first sentence.